# Circular Reference Found. Property of class datatype inside class

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

```
 public class childrens     {
        public ICollection<childrens> children { get; set; }
        public data data { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    } 


 public static childrens GetJsonData()
        {
            childrens rootNode = new childrens();
            rootNode.data = new data();
            rootNode.id = "root";
            rootNode.name = "Top Albums";

            childrens objChildren547 = new childrens();
            objChildren547.data = new data { playcount = 547, area = "547" };
            objChildren547.id = "artist_A Perfect Circle";
            objChildren547.name = "A Perfect Circle";
            rootNode.children = new List<childrens>();
            rootNode.children.Add(objChildren547);

            childrens objChildren276 = new childrens();
            objChildren276.data = new data { playcount = 276, artist = "A Perfect Circle", image = "http:\\/\\/userserve-ak.last.fm\\/serve\\/300x300\\/11403219.jpg", area = "276" };
            objChildren276.id = "album-Thirteenth Step";
            objChildren276.name = "Thirteenth Step";
            objChildren547.children = new List<childrens>();
            objChildren547.children.Add(objChildren276);

            childrens objChildren271 = new childrens();
            objChildren271.data = new data { playcount = 271, artist = "A Perfect Circle", image = "http:\\/\\/userserve-ak.last.fm\\/serve\\/300x300\\/11403219.jpg", area = "271" };
            objChildren271.id = "album-Mer De Noms";
            objChildren271.name = "Mer De Noms";
            objChildren547.children.Add(objChildren271);
            return rootNode;
        }

   [WebMethod]
        public static HttpResponseMessage GetJsonData()
        {
            var data = jsondata.GetJsonData();
            return new HttpResponseMessage { Content = new ObjectContent(typeof(childrens), data, new System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter() { SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.None, MaxDepth = 10 } }) };
            //return data;
        }
```

The above code gives me an error "Circular Reference Found". I used the property reference handling but it didn't work.

How can I achieve this using NewtonSoft.Json Library to serialize it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the [ReferenceLoopHandling option of the serialization settings](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SerializationSettings.htm) to `ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize`. You pass the options into the `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` method I believe.